# Some marker props not updating when state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm building a gig guide with React Native and react native maps.

The home screen features a map with markers showing the current day's gigs. The user can see the upcoming day's gig by pressing the 'Next day's gigs' button, which renders new markers for the cuurent day on the map.

The user can tap on a marker to show gig information in a popup, but **here's the problem: if the user then navigates to the next day's gigs, the data in the popup doesn't change**. So you have the information for yesterday's gig being displayed in the current day's popup, as follows:

**Initial gig for 20th December**:

[image]

**What the map *should* show when user navigates to next day (21st December)**:

[image]

**What the map *actually* shows - note that it's displaying the previous day gig information**

[image]

What's confusing is that the marker *coordinates* are updated when the gig date changes, but the description and title props don't:

```
        {gigsToday.map((gig, i) => (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: gig.location.latitude,     // <--- This changes the way it should
              longitude: gig.location.longitude, // <--- This changes the way it should
            }}
            image={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
            description = {gig.venue}  // <--- This doesn't change the way it should
            title = {gig.gigName}   //<--- This doesn't change the way it should
          />
        ))}
      </MapView>
```

Any ideas how to fix this, so the marker information changes when data changes? Or at least make the popup disappear when the user navigates to the next day?

Full code for map component (I've left out the styling sheet to make more concise):

**GigMaps.js**

```
import { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Pressable,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import { Marker, Callout } from "react-native-maps";
import CalloutView from "./CalloutView";
import { mapStyle } from "../util/mapStyle";
import { useGigs } from "../hooks/useGigs";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";


const GigMap = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [selectedDateMs, setSelectedDateMs] = useState(Date.now());
  const  [ currentDayGigs,setCurrentDayGigs ] = useState([])
  const gigs = useGigs();


  //generates current date in format DD/MM/YYYY
  const selectedDateString = useMemo(() => {
    const date = new Date(selectedDateMs);
    const dateToString = date.toString().slice(0,15)
    return dateToString // returns in form 'Tue Dec 20 2022'
  }, [selectedDateMs]);


  //Filtering through gigs to return only current day's gigs
  const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => {
    const gigDate1 = new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000)   
    const gigDate2 = gigDate1.toString().slice(0,15) //return form 'Tue Dec 20 2022'
    return gigDate2 === selectedDateString
  })

  // const generateGigsToday = () => {
  //   useEffect(() => {
  //     const gigsToday = gigs.filter((gig) => {
  //       const gigDate1 = new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000)   
  //       const gigDate2 = gigDate1.toString().slice(0,15) //return form 'Tue Dec 20 2022'
  //       return gigDate2 === selectedDateString
  //     })
  //     setCurrentDayGigs(gigsToday)
  //   },[selectedDateMs])
  // }

  // generateGigsToday()

  // const gigsToday = useMemo(() => {
  //   return (
  //     gigs.filter((gig) => {
  //       const gigDate1 = new Date(gig.dateAndTime.seconds*1000)
  //       const gigDate2 = gigDate1.toString().slice(0,15)
  //       return gigDate2 === selectedDateString
  //     })
  //   )
  // },[selectedDateMs])


  //increments date by amount
  const addDays = (amount) => {
    setSelectedDateMs((curr) => curr + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * amount);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.headerText}>{`Gigs on ${selectedDateString}`}</Text>

      <View style={styles.imageText}>
        <Text style = {styles.subHeader}>Tap on</Text>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
        />
        <Text style = {styles.subHeader}> to see gig info</Text>
      </View>

      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: -41.29416,
          longitude: 174.77782,
          latitudeDelta: 0.03,
          longitudeDelta: 0.03,
        }}
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle}
      >
        {gigsToday.map((gig, i) => (
          <Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: gig.location.latitude,
              longitude: gig.location.longitude,
            }}
            image={require("../assets/Icon_Gold_48x48.png")}
            description = {gig.venue}
            title = {gig.gigName}
          />
        ))}
      </MapView>

      <View style={styles.buttonOptions}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(-1)} style = {styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={36} color="#778899" />
          <Text style = {{fontFamily:'Helvetica-Neue', color:'#778899'}}>Previous day's gigs</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addDays(1)} style = {styles.touchable}>
          <AntDesign name="caretright" size={36} color="#778899" />
          <Text style = {{fontFamily:'Helvetica-Neue',color:'#778899'}}>Next day's gigs</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>

  );
};
```

Comment: Smells like open Callout does not re-render on prop change.

Comment: @ghybs my thoughts too. Any suggestions on how to dimiss the callout when upon pressing "gigs next" or "gigs previous"?